# Why does the terminal command “w” output the 3 same users in the macOS?

Tags: shell, users

I am logged in to my account. Using the terminal I type the command `w` and this is the result.

```
 1:07  up 4 days,  4:23, 3 users, load averages: 2.39 2.20 2.24
USER     TTY      FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
bwayne console  -                Sat20   4days -
bwayne s000     -                 1:07       - w
bwayne console  -                Tue01   2days -
```

Note the `3 users` in the first line. Why does it show same 3 users? Am I pwned?

Answer (score 0):

It just means that you currently have three terminals / ssh sessions / whatever open. Open an additional terminal and `w` will show you four logins. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: I don't have 2 terminals open. That is the thing. I have a single shell open. yet it still says 2 consoles. 1. 7 days idle now, and the other 5 days idle. I have zero ssh connections, with the service turned off. It would make sense for a single console and the w command, but why the other one. I have restarted and still the same. Is it from a networked device? and how can I close it.

Comment: the 3rd user eventually disappeared, so now it shows only the two. 1. logged into the machine, and 2. logged into terminal. I still don't understand why there was a 3rd for the longest time, but seems to have resolved itself.